# MYSQL - how do i select no more than x rows max with the same field value y?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, limit

this question is a bit tricky to formulate, so probably has been asked before.

i am selecting rows from a table of interrelating data.  i only want a maximum of n rows which have the same value x of some field/column in the table to show up in my set.  there is a global limit, in essence i always want the query to return the same amount of rows, with no more than n rows sharing value x.  how do i do this?

here's an example of the data (dots are supposed to indicate that this table is large, let's say 20000 rows of data):

```
some_table
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
| id |  some_id | some_column | another_id |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
|  1 |       10 |       value |          8 |
|  2 |       10 |       value |          5 |
|  3 |       10 |       value |          2 |
|  4 |       20 |       value |          3 |
|  5 |       30 |       value |          9 |
|  6 |       30 |       value |          1 |
|  7 |       30 |       value |          4 |
|  8 |       30 |       value |          6 |
|  9 |       30 |       value |          7 |
| 10 |       40 |       value |         10 |
| .. |      ... |         ... |        ... |
| .. |      ... |         ... |        ... |
| .. |      ... |         ... |        ... |
| .. |      ... |         ... |        ... |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
```

now here's my select:

```
select * from some_table where some_column="value" order by another_id limit 6
```

but instead of returning rows with another_id = 1 thru 6 i want to get no more than 2 rows with the same value of some_id.  in other words, i'd like to get:

```
result set
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
| id |  some_id | some_column | another_id |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
|  6 |       30 |       value |          1 |
|  3 |       10 |       value |          2 |
|  1 |       10 |       value |          3 |
|  7 |       30 |       value |          4 |
|  4 |       20 |       value |          8 |
| 10 |       40 |       value |         10 |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
```

note that the results are ordered by another_id, but there are no more than 2 results with the same value of some_id.

how can i best (meaning preferably in one query and reasonably fast) get there?  thanks!

Comment: Is **2** fixed or you can have some other k instead of 2? What is the size of the table?

Comment: as stated above, k / n is variable.  size of the table shouldn't matter, but isn't fixed either.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, some_id, some_column, another_id from (
    select 
    t.*,
    @rn := if(@prev = some_id, @rn + 1, 1) as rownumber,
    @prev := some_id
    from some_table t
    , (select @prev := null, @rn := 0) var_init
    where some_column="value"
    order by some_id, id
) sq where rownumber <= 2
order by another_id;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b885/2/0)

First we order by some_id, id in the subquery to do the right calculations. Then we order by another_id in the outer query to have correct ordering.

Comment: thanks, this works for my sample data in its native ordering.  how can i make it work regardless of ordering or if the data becomes scrambled in order or input / added out of order?

Comment: ... if only i could somehow create a temp array to keep count of the distinct, different some_id instances..?  or perhaps there's a way to count / review the already fetched data?

Comment: Fixed that, please have a try again.

Comment: thanks, and sorry, the sample data originally provided was not properly illustrating my problem.  i have now updated it, added another column by which the sorting / ordering *has* to take place.  'order by some_id' will not work, and re-sorting once i have the result set won't work either because i'm only grabbing a portion (see 'limit 6' above).  any other ideas?

Comment: Updated my post again.

Comment: i take it back, this still messes up the ordering.  the reason is that, as i said, we are only grabbing a small portion of the table data (in my real-life scenario i'm getting something like 20 out of 2000), and this portion represents the top tier according to the final ordering (e.g. by another_id).  if we order differently (e.g. by some_id) first and limit the result set, then we are definitely ending up with completely different data, even if we sort it again a second time.  does that make sense?

Comment: It would make the problem clearer if you added the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: ye this is what i was afraid of.  i've updated the original post with a sample result and an indication that the data table is large.  tbf, i think your code will still work for what's there, but the point here is that i dont want to be grabbing the entire table to ultimately arrive at just my top 6 (tho i am doing something similar now with "query slices", re-querying, etc).  ... can i maybe create a temporary table for some_id counts?  and then check that table for every row grabbed?  all in one query??